# C++ using arrays as multidimensional despite initalising it as 1D with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

apperently this code works.

```
int main()
{
const int size = 5;
int *triangle[size], i, j;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        triangle[i][j] = i + 1;
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        cout << triangle[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    delete [] triangle[i];

return 0;
}
```

It gives it  output
    1
    22
    333
    4444
    55555

But isn't writing `int*triangle[ size]` shows that is a 1D array, we dont specify anything about the second parameter. But then we use at it is like a 2D array by writing  `triangle[i][j] = i + 1;`I dont understand where that j(second parameter) come from. Shouldn't it give a compile error or something?

Comment: For practising pointers, how this comment can help my problem?

Comment: A 1D array can be interpreted as a 2D array and vice versa. What's not clear about that?

Comment: You might be surprised, but there are no 2 or N dimensional arrays in C/C++ where N is greater than 1. The only array type available is a single-dimension array.

Comment: A 1D array can be interpreted as an nD array of any arbitrary dimensionality and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

`int *triangle[size]` is an array of pointers.  In your for loop you do

```
triangle[i] = new int[i + 1]
```

which sets each pointer to point to an array.  We put that together and

```
triangle[i][2]
         +  +
         |  +> access the element of the array the ith pointer points to
         |
         +-> Accesses the ith pointer
```

Comment: Looks like someone got their hands on AsciiFlow :)

Comment: @SergeyA Well, I couldn't not try it out :)

Answer (score 3):

What you have here isn't a 2-dimensional array.  It is a one-dimensional array of pointers to `int`s, each of which happens to be the first one in another array.

```
int *triangle[size]
```

This declares an array of `size` (five in this case) pointers to `int`s.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        triangle[i][j] = i + 1;
}
```

In this loop, `triangle[i] = new int[i + 1]` allocates an array of `i + 1` `int`s and stores a pointer to its first element in `triangle[i]`.

In the end, you end up with this structure:

```
triangle
 +---+
 |   |  +---+
 | +--->+ 1 |
 |   |  +---+
 +---+
 |   |  +---+---+
 | +--->+ 2 | 2 |
 |   |  +---+---+
 +---+
 |   |  +---+---+---+
 | +--->+ 3 | 3 | 3 |
 |   |  +---+---+---+
 +---+
 |   |  +---+---+---+---+
 | +--->+ 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
 |   |  +---+---+---+---+
 +---+
 |   |  +---+---+---+---+---+
 | +--->+ 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
 |   |  +---+---+---+---+---+
 +---+
```

When you access `triangle[i][j]` you're fist looking up the `i`th pointer to `int` in `triangle`, and then looking up the `j`th `int` in the array pointed to by that pointer.

Comment: Did you draw this by hand?  It looks really nice

Comment: @NathanOliver, No, I jused [ASCIIFlow Infinity](http://asciiflow.com/).  It's really helpful for questions like this where a simple picture can make things much clearer than text.

Comment: Oh.  That is a really cool utility.  I'm adding that to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

> But isn't writing `int*triangle[ size]` shows that is a 1D array?

You're right, it is a 1D array. But it's a 1D array of integer pointers and (spoiler alert) each pointer can point to its own `int` array. So while you could argue this is a 1D array of integer pointers, usually we call this a 2D array (if the pointers point to arrays).

> But then we use at it is like a 2D array by writing  `triangle[i][j] = i + 1;`

Remember that the subscript operator (`[]`) is just syntactic sugar. So `x[y]` is exactly the same as `*(x+y)`. So what that really says is `*(triangle[i]+j)` or, take the pointer at index `i`, increment it by `j` and get me the value at that location, which makes sense since you've allocated a dynamic array for `triangle[i]` to point to.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to remember that there are no 2 (3, 4, 5, N...) dimensional arrays in C/C++ where. The only available array is 1-dimension array.

When you declare array as

```
int x[3][4];
```

You are not declaring a two-dimensional array of integers. Instead, you are declaring an array of 4 elements, where every element is an array of 3 elements.

Conversely, you can declare an array of pointers to integers:

```
int* x[4];
```

Now every pointer can point to an individual integer or a first element in the series of integers. Since arrays are convertible to pointers to their elements, this is a valid code:

```
int* x[2];

int x1[3];
int x2[3];

x[0] = x1;
x[1] = x2;
```

Comment: "*You are not declaring a two-dimensional array of integers. Instead, you are declaring an array of 4 elements, where every element is an array of 3 elements.*" That to me sounds like the definition of a two-dimensional array. If that's not, then what **is** a 2D array?

Comment: @scohe001 you might find it purely terminological, but to me there a difference. For example, it helps with questions like that, when you understand that an element of this single-dimensional array can be anything, including another array.

Comment: That's fair, but I'm still not sure I understand what you consider to actually be a 2D array if it's not that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @scohe001, to me the most important thing is a type system/object . There is a type for a row on a 'quasi'-2D array (an array) and an object, of which you can take an address. For column, there is no object and no type. In true two-dimensional arrays there would be either no type for both rows and columns, or there would be a type for both. I also find that it  also helps to understand (intuitively) why single-dimensional arrays decays to simple pointer, but two-dimensional arrays does not decay to simple pointer to pointer.

Comment: Ahh so you're saying in a "true 2D array" there'd be no way to pull a row or pull a column? It'd be something like a `std::map<std::pair<int, int>>` where you ***have*** to supply both row and col to play?

Comment: @scohe001 or you'd be able to have a type and object for both or for none. There would be a true symmetry there. Again, this is purely terminological, but I remember that understanding that helped me, for example, when I was just learning C.

Answer (score 1):

Many students struggle with this concept at first, but once you get it, it's easy peasy.

```
int *c[5];   // An array of pointers --> contains 5 pointers 
int **a;     // A pointer to a pointer
int *b       // A pointer
```

You already know that to make b point to an array, we have to do something like this:

```
int *b = new int[5]; // b points to an array of 5 integers
```

Since `c` is an array of **int pointers** (like b), `c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]` are pointers. So we can get a "2D array" by initializing all those pointers, as your code did:

`c[0] = new int[5]; // c[0] points to an array of 5 integers`

Now `a` is a pointer to a pointer, so if you want to make a "2D array", you need to make "`a` point to an array of pointers which points to an array of integers," as such:

`a = new int*[5]; // a points to an array that holds 5 pointers`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   a[i] = new int[5]; // these 5 pointers again point to an array of 5 integers
} // in the end, you have a 5x5 array.
```